# Andventure game problems, moving between rooms Python

Tags: python, text-based

So far I am able to get to all rooms except from fight to stairs. I get the description for the stairs to show up but when I try to give it the next direction nothing is recognized.

heres the code:

```
def playGame():
   location = "Porch"
   showIntroduction()
   while not (location == "Exit"):
       showRoom(location)
       direction = requestString("Which direction")
       printNow("You typed: " + direction)
       location = pickRoom(direction, location)

# The instructions for the game      
def showIntroduction():
  printNow ("Welcome to the Adventure House!")
  printNow ("In each room, you will be told which directions you can go.")
  printNow ("You can move north, south, east, or west by typing")
  printNow ("that direction into the box.")
  printNow ("you can also pick up items that you will need on your journey")
  printNow ("They will present themselves in the text, to pick them up simplily type    there name")
  printNow ("Type help to replay this introduction.")
  printNow ("Type quit or exit to end the program.")

#This is called in the global defination of Inventory , makes and array
def createInventory():
   inv = range(11)
   inv[10] = "made"
   return inv

 # Main Inventory
 Inventory = createInventory()

 # Populating given inventory aray with items to be used throughout the game.
 def createItems(inv):
   items = inv
   items[1] = "Axe"
   items[2] = "Gas"
   items[3] = "keys"
   items[4] = "gun"
   items[5] = "note"
   items[9] = "full" 

# Check if the item passed to it is still in the inventory array
def checkItems(item):
    items = Inventory
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if items[i] == item:
            return "yes"
        return "no"



 #Put an item in the inventory (Key words : grab /  item name)
 def stockInventory(item):
    inv = Inventory
    for i in range (11):
       if inv[i] == 0:
          inv[i] = item
          break
    return inv

 #Check for an item to make text appear.
 def checkInventory(item):
    inv = Inventory
    for i in range(0, 11):
        if item == inv[i]:
           return "yes"
        return "no"


# A helper function that calls specific room description 
# functions based on the value of the parameter room 
def showRoom(room):
   printNow("============")
   if room == "Porch":
      showPorch()
   elif room == "Entryway":
      showEntryway()
   elif room == "Kitchen":
      showKitchen()
   elif room == "LivingRoom":
      showLR()
   elif room == "DiningRoom":
      showDR()
   elif room == "Stairs" :
      showStairs()
   elif room == "Nurcery":
      showNurcery()
   elif room == "Hole":
      showHoleFalling()
   elif room == "Basement":
      showBasement()
  elif room == "BasementW":
    showBasementW()
  elif room == "BasementN":
     showBasementN()
  elif room == "BasementS":
     showBasementS()
  elif room == "BasementE":
     showBasementE()
  elif room == "frontYardFight":
      showFight()
  elif room == "Car":
     showCar()
  elif room == "win":
     Winning()
  elif room == "Fight":
     showFight1()
  # Add rooms above this line!
  else:  #This clause should never execute
       printNow("I don't recognize the room")

  # This function specifies what room is entered based on the current room
  # and the direction requested by the user.
def pickRoom (direction, room):
if (direction == "quit"  or direction == "exit"):
    printNow("Goodbye!")
    return "Exit"
elif direction == "help" or direction == "Help":
    showIntroduction()
    return room

elif room == "Porch":
    if direction == "north":
       return "Entryway"
    elif direction == "truck":
        printNow ("The truck is out of gas and your keys seem to be missing. you return to the porch")
    else:
       printNow("There's no way to go that direction.")
       return room

elif room == "Entryway":
    if direction == "north":
       return "Kitchen"
    elif direction == "south":
       return "Porch"
    elif direction == "east":
       return "LivingRoom"
    elif direction == "read":
        printNow ("This house will be your doom")
    else:
       printNow ("The is not the correct word")
       return room

elif room == "Kitchen":
    if direction == "south":
       return "Entryway"
    elif direction == "east":
       return "DiningRoom"
    elif direction == "west":
        answer = checkInventory("Axe")
        if answer == "yes":
            printNow (" You feel the urge to get shinning  on this door, you decide to swing your axe and break it")
            return "Fight"
        else:
            printNow (" the door is locked, find a a way to open it.")
            return room




elif room == "Fight":
  answer = checkInventory("Axe")
  if direction ==  "swing":
       printNow ("You landed your blow! it's down!")
       return "Stairs"
  else:
       printNow(" wrong keyword ")
       return room
  return "Stairs"

elif room == "LivingRoom":
    if direction == "north":
       return "DiningRoom"
    elif direction == "west":
       return "Entryway"
    elif direction == ("axe" or "Axe"):
       stockInventory("Axe")
       printNow(" You grabbed the Axe ")
       return room
    else:
       printNow ("You have the wrong keyword.")
       return room

elif room == "DiningRoom":
    if direction == "south":
       return "LivingRoom"
    elif direction == "west":
       return "Kitchen"
    elif direction == ("Gas" or "gas"):
       stockInventory("Gas")
       printNow (" you grabbed the gas ")
    else:
       printNow ("You have the wrong keyword.")
       return room

elif room == "Stairs":
     if direction == "up":
        return "TopHall"
     elif direction == ("keys" or "Keys"):
        stockInventory("Keys")
        printNow (" You got the Keys!")
     else:
        printNow ("You have the wrong keyword.")
        return room

elif room == "TopHall":
    if direction == "north":
       return "Hole"
    elif direction == "west":
        return "Nurcery"
    else:
        printNow(" You have the wrong keyword. ")
        return room

elif room == "Nurcery":
    if direction == "west":
       return "TopHall"
    else:
       printNow(" You have the wrong keyword. ")
       return room

elif room == "Hole":
   return "Basement"

elif room == "Basement":
   if direction == "west":
      return "BasementW"
   elif direction == "north":
      return "BasementN"
   elif direction == "south":
      return "BasementS"
   elif direction == "east":
      return "BasementE"
   else:
     printNow(" That is the wrong word ")
     return room

elif room == "BasementW":
   if direction == "east":
      return "Basement"
   else:
     printNow(" That is the wrong word ")
     return room

elif room == "BasementN":
   if direction == "south":
      return "Basement"
   elif direction == "wall":
      return "FrontYard"
   else:
     printNow(" That is the wrong word ")
     return room

elif room == "basementS":
   if direction == "north":
     return "Basement"
   elif direction == ("gun" or "Gun"):
     stockInventory("gun") 
     printNow (" you got the Gun!")
   else:
     printNow(" That is the wrong word ")
     return room

elif room == "BasementE":
   if direction == "west":
     return "Basement"
   else:
     printNow(" That is the wrong word ")
     return room

elif room == "frontYardFight":
   if direction == "shoot":
       answer = checkInventory("gun")
       if answer == "yes" or "Yes":
           printNow(" You shoot the monster straight in the head" )
           return "Car"
       else:
          return "quit"
   else:
     printNow(" That is the wrong word ")
     return room


elif room == "Car":
   answer1 = checkInventory("Keys")
   answer2 = checkInventory("Gas")
   if answer1 and answer2 == "Yes" or "yes":
       return "win"
   else:
       printNow("your missing something")
       return "Porch"




#add rooms above this line!
else:  # this clause should never execute!
    printNow("An undefined room has been detected.")
    return "Porch"


######  a group of functions that print room descriptions    

def showPorch():
   printNow("You wake from a deep slumber, you're lieing on the porch of an abandonded house")
   printNow("The windows are broken.  It's a dark and stormy night")
   printNow("Your truck is sitting in the parking lot, when you examine it, it is out of gas and your keys are gone")
   printNow("You can go north into the house if you dare.")
```

and so on

Comment: The code as you've copied it here is indented wrongly. Please check the indentation in your original. The clause `elif room == "Stairs":` seems to have 5 spaces instead of 4, which might be why it is not working (although if that is so then the programme should throw an error)

Comment: The program as it's pasted will raise an `IndentationError` before even getting there, because `Inventory = createInventory()` is indented 1 space…

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess here, but I'm guessing this error is the one you're worried about:

```
 elif direction == ("keys" or "Keys"):
```

That doesn't do what you think it does. `("keys" or "Keys")` is the same thing as `"keys"`. So, this the same as `elif direction == "keys":`.

You wanted one of these:

```
elif direction == "keys" or direction == "Keys":
elif direction in ("keys", "Keys"):
elif direction.lower() == "keys":
```

Or, even better, change `playGame` to call `pickRoom(direction.lower(), location)`, and then all throughout `pickRoom` you can just compare to the lower-case strings.

You get this right many times, like here:

```
elif direction == "help" or direction == "Help":
```

… but you also get it wrong in various other places, and you will have to fix all of them.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that in the function `pickRoom`, not all of the branches of the long `if...elif...else` return a value. In the following section, if the user types 'keys', then no room will be returned and the programme should output "An undefined room has been detected." in the subsequent loop.

```
elif room == "Stairs":
    if direction == "up":
        return "TopHall"
    elif direction == ("keys" or "Keys"):
        stockInventory("Keys")
        printNow (" You got the Keys!")
    else:
        printNow ("You have the wrong keyword.")
        return room
```

A simple way to deal with this would be to add `return room` at the end of the function, to deal with all remaining cases where it has not previously returned.